# EditText drawable hides after setting tint programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, kotlin

I have two `EditText` in my layout. I am using `TextInputLayout` and added `drawableLeft`, now I am trying to change its tint which is working fine for username field but it hides left drawable icon for password field. Below is the code, please guide me what I am doing wrong.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="@dimen/margin_300"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">



<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                android:id="@+id/userIDLayout"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/appCompatImageView4">

                                <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                                    android:id="@+id/edit_user_id"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_user_login"
                                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_10"
                                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_user_login"
                                    android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                                    android:hint="@string/txt_user_hint"
                                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionNext"
                                    android:inputType="number"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_16" />
                            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


                            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                                android:id="@+id/userPasswordLayout"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/appCompatImageView5"
                                app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

                                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                                    android:id="@+id/edit_user_password"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_user_password"
                                    android:drawablePadding="@dimen/margin_10"
                                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_user_password"
                                    android:drawableTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                                    android:hint="@string/txt_pin_hint"
                                    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionDone"
                                    android:inputType="numberPassword"
                                    android:maxLength="4"
                                    android:maxLines="1"
                                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_size_16" />
                            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

                        </LinearLayout>
```

Below is the code that I am using to change tint programmatically:

```
fun changeEditTextDrawableColor(colorId: Int, drawableId: Int, resource: EditText) {
    var drawable = resources.getDrawable(drawableId)
    drawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(drawable)
    DrawableCompat.setTint(drawable, resources.getColor(colorId))
    DrawableCompat.setTintMode(drawable, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN)

    resource!!.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(drawable, null, null, null)
}
```

Comment: Can you pl give try by removing              android:inputType="numberPassword" from your password edit text and if it work then I can suggest you way to fix

Comment: Its working fine if i remove `app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"`. i tested it. i guess the problem is happening coz of password toggle

Comment: Not sure app:"property" can be set at run time or not but it can help you to fix your issue

Comment: you mind if you could elaborate more.

Comment: Try calling `inValidate()` to the `View`.

Comment: inValidate() is not working :(

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds` change it to `setCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds` and it will start appearing.

Comment: This solution fixed an issue I had trying to set a drawable programatically (with no tint) onto an AutoCompleteTextView. Thanks!